# Debug points not working in eclipse for a remote application

Tags: eclipse, debugging, weblogic

I have a Java application running on a WebLogic server. I have kept breakpoints in the `doPost()` method of the servlet I want to invoke on that server.

When I invoke that servlet, it is not stopping at any of the debug points. The WebLogic port used by the application is `3304`. When I give this port in the debug configuration it throws the following error:

> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
>   Connection refused: connect

If I give any other ports, e.g. `3305`, `3303` it opens the debug view, but the application cannot be debugged.

Comment: I found the port was having an error. So I restarted the server now I am able to create a debug configuration with 3304 port but the control does not stop at the debug points. I read similar posts on stackflow but could not find an answer. I restarted my eclipse, and also my machine, but of no help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you started the VM with these params, which exposes the correct port and starts the server in debug mode.

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=<port number>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JVM will be running on debug port 3304 only. So other ports will not work. The error you get may be because, the debug connection to this port is already made by another machine or client, or an existing connection started by you was not terminated. You will get the exact stacktrace from eclipse, when you click on More details>.

```
Quick Try: Restart the JVM.(Sorry for this tip if its a production server)
```

Comment: I only get "Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect" in the stacktrace. If anyone is connected to this server how may I verify this??

Comment: restarting jvm will flush all the active connections. restart the jvm with debug port as a different one. try to connect again.